# Directory.Move(SourcePath, Destinationpath ) is failing in c#

Tags: c#, file

I believed this to be really simple but somehow i am making a mistake.I am trying to copy one folder to another location

```
Directory.Move(SourcePath, Destinationpath )
```

This expression is failing.  The exception thrown is "cannot create file that already exists"

Comment: clearly as the error states - the folder/file already exists. Did you verify it does exist? What are your values for SourcePath and DestinationPath?

Comment: Does another folder of the same name exist in the destination location? According to MSDN, trying to do that will throw. You should delete the destination folder first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you say you want to "**copy** one folder to another".

`Directory.Move()`, doesn't *copy*: as its name implies, it **moves** a directory. Take at look at the documentation on how to copy files:

- [.Net 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (see here for [an asynchronous approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))
- [.Net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (see here for an [asynchronous approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

The `Move` call is failing because a directory or file in the move operation exists at the specified location (as the exception noted).  In order to fix this you need to ensure that no file or directory exists at the destination.  The easiest way is to first delete that path

Do not run this function unless you are OK with unconditionally deleting data at `DestinationPath`.

```
static void MyMove(string sourcePath, string destPath) { 
  try { 
    Directory.Delete(destPath, recursive: true);
  } catch { 
    // Don't care if this fails.  If the file didn't exist, great, if the 
    // file can't be deleted will still get an error in Move.  Just try
    // Move at this point 
  }

  Directory.Move(sourcePath, destPath);
}
```